# Verilog simulation error in Modelsim 10.4 SE

Tags: verilog, modelsim

CODE://Gate level description of a 2x4_decoder

```
module decoder_2X4_gates(D,A,B);
output [0:3] D;
input  A,B;
wire A_not, B_not;
not f1(A_not,A);
not f2(B_not,B);
nand f4(D[0],A_not,B_not);
nand f5(D[1],A_not,B);
nand f6(D[2],A,B_not);
nand f7(D[3],A,B);
endmodule;
```

ERROR:
can't read "Startup(-L)": no such element in array

## Load canceled

Comment: The error does not come from the block of code shown, it compiles fine in Modelsim 10.1d [on EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/8V2).

Comment: ya, but this error comes while i am doing the simulation. can u please tell me what all variable should i drag in the wave window to see their wave output. This error occurs when i am forcing some values and then trying to see its output.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include what your doing to cause the error. Is it from just running the simulation or when adding signals to the waveform window. thanks

Comment: I add the variables in the wave window and then i force the values on them by right clicking on them. I am pretty new to modelsim so only know this way to give some input and see its output. If u can suggest anything else it would help me a lot. THANKS

Answer (score 1):

Not sure on the issue with forcing values from the waveform window, but I would suggest creating a testbench, whereby you can just execute the simulation and see results.

ie:

```
module tb;

  reg A;       //Test Input
  reg B;       //Test Input
  wire [3:0] D;//Test Output

  //Device Under Test
  decoder_2X4_gates dut (
    .A (A),
    .B (B),
    .D (D)
  );

  //Test Program
  initial begin
    A=1'b0;
    B=1'b0;
    #1ps $displayb(D);

    #1ns;
    A=1'b1;
    B=1'b0;
    #1ps $displayb(D);

    #1ns;
    A=1'b0;
    B=1'b1;
    #1ps $displayb(D);


    #1ns;
    A=1'b1;
    B=1'b1;
    #1ps $displayb(D);

    $finish;
  end

endmodule
```

There is a working example of this on [EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/8V2).

Comment: I do not have much idea about test bench and all, but still, thank you for your valuable inputs and time.

Comment: @AbhishekTyagi That is a testbench in the answer, it instantiates the module your trying to test, and drives values in while displaying the output.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was receiving the very same error. After digging I figured out that the license file wasn't installed. After installing the License file I was able to move forward as expected.